# Cannot set jquery dialog.InnerHtml(some-content) without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my JS file, I am trying to set the content to a poped up dialog. In firebug, I saw the dialog opens and it hangs even after I set the content of it by `$(dialog).InnerHtml`.
But this works when I refresh the page.

Any particular reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot set `.innerHTML` directly off the jQuery object. You need to set `$.html()` instead.

```
// jQuery doesn't have an innerHTML property, so this is wrong
$("#dialog").innerHTML = "This is the wrong way";

// jQuery has an html() method that sets the html within your dialog
$("#dialog").html( "And this is the correct way" );
```

Keep in mind that when you're dealing with jQuery, you're dealing with an object, and not an element. Attributes like `.innerHTML` exist on elements within the DOM, but not within the jQuery object. jQuery provides methods like `$.html()` so that you don't have to ever touch `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do:

In javascript:

```
document.getElementById('dialog').innerHTML = 'something';
```

In Jquery :

```
$("#dialog").html('something');
```